# Output a result file from a original file with @nameuse

Tags: expansion, output, csname

i have a file a.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\gdef\wbsinput@files{,\jobname}
\gdef\wbsinput@current{\jobname}

\long\def\wbs#1#2{
   {\expandafter\ifx\csname wbsinput@\wbsinput@current @#1\endcsname \relax
      \global\@namedef{wbsinput@\wbsinput@current @#1}{#2\par}%
      \else
    \global\expandafter\addto\csname wbsinput@\wbsinput@current
      @#1\endcsname{#2\par}\fi}
}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}



\newcommand{\print}[1]{%
    \print@all{#1}
}

\newcommand{\print@all}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\@for\noexpand\next:=\wbsinput@files\noexpand\do
  }\x{\print@one{\next}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\print@one}[2]{%
  \@nameuse{wbsinput@#1@#2}\par
}


\makeatother

\wbs{1.1}{This is a line 1.}

\wbs{1.1}{This is a line 2.}

\print{1.1}

\end{document}
```

and i want to get a result b.tex like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a line 1.

This is a line 2.

\end{document}
```

what should I do ？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and write to a file using functionality provided by [`newfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/newfile). The following minimal example does that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}

\newoutputstream{myout}
\openoutputfile{b.tex}{myout}
\begin{writeverbatim}{myout}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\end{writeverbatim}

\begin{document}

test

\addtostream{myout}{This is a line 1.}

\addtostream{myout}{This is a line 2.}

\addtostream{myout}{\string\end{document}}

\closeoutputstream{myout}

\end{document}
```

The file `b.tex` is created that contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a line 1.
This is a line 2.
\end{document}
```